# Factory reset not improving performance

Tags: factory-reset, 9.0-pie

I've been having some problems with my Razer Phone 2, running Pie.  I wasn't getting MMS messages from some people.  I tried doing a factory reset without restoring any my my data.  It doesn't work well at all.  After the factory reset, and reinstalling both the Amazon app and the Audible apps, they are so slow as to be unusable.  Is there a better way to do a factory reset than through the System > Reset options >Erase all data (factory reset)?

Comment: Performing a factory reset via Android settings app is the recommended way. When using other methods (e.g. from recovery you may end up in the Factory Reset Protection asking for your last Google password).

Comment: After a factory reset the device does a lot of work in the background this will make the device seem slower.